# Poller bean not being used by @Poller in @InboundChannelAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I've been trying to convert my XML Spring Integration job to Java and I've encountered some difficulties. One of them is that I can't seem to detect and use my Poller bean with the `@Poller` annotation on my InboundChannelAdapter.

```
@Bean(name = "startPeriodicTrigger")
public PeriodicTrigger startPeriodicTrigger() {
    PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger = new PeriodicTrigger(appProperties.getStartRate());
    periodicTrigger.setFixedRate(true);
    return periodicTrigger;
}

@Bean
public PollerMetadata startPoller(@Qualifier("startPeriodicTrigger") PeriodicTrigger startPeriodicTrigger) {
    PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
    pollerMetadata.setTrigger(startPeriodicTrigger);
    return pollerMetadata;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "initTimestampChannel", poller = @Poller("startPoller"))
public MessageSource<?> buildTasksRequest() {
    MethodInvokingMessageSource source = new MethodInvokingMessageSource();
    source.setObject(tasksService);
    source.setMethodName("requestAllTasks");
    return source;
}
```

My `@InboundChannelAdapter` is always created before my pollers, so it defaults to using some uninitialized poller with values like `0ms` as fixedRate, instead of the `30000ms` setted in my `startPeriodicTrigger` bean.

Should I drop the `@Bean` on my `@InboudChannelAdapter` ?

Comment: That's impossible. You use an explicit `startPoller` bean name. And there is no "some default poller with values like 0ms". Would be great if you can share a simple project on GitHub to let us to reproduce and play. Thanks

Comment: It's a corporate project, unfortunately I can't share the whole project. I can share a bigger sample of the Integration Configuration class if that might help my case. Also, when I delete the @Bean on my  `@InboudChannelAdapter` I load the correct poller ... but I have a `no suitable HttpMessageConverter` after returning the `MessageSource` in `this.messagingTemplate.send(getOutputChannel(), message);` (`SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java`)

Comment: Well, you see I didn't tell that I need your whole project. The only request is: please, share a *simple* project to reproduce. The `HttpMessageConverter` issue is somehow not relevant here and just makes things in this post more complicated. You shouldn't drop that `@Bean` because it is a `MessageSource` not some other possible POJO method invocation.